# I need explanation to an illustration in Gill Arthur's Finite State Machine text

Tags: computer-science, state-machine, hint

In the mentioned text, on page 15, there is the illustration of a computing device with two input lines (please, see reference image(s) below).

Whereas I understand (I think) how the excitation (X) and response (Z) alphabets (i.e. the set of ordered 2-tuples denoted by X and Z respectively) of the system were determined, that is, by Cartesian products of the sets of input lines (X<sup>(1)</sup> and X<sup>(2)</sup>) and output lines (Z<sup>(1)</sup> and Z<sup>(2)</sup>) respectively; I do not seem to understand how Z<sup>(1)</sup> = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and Z<sup>(2)</sup> = {0, 1, 2, 3} where arrived at from the generating expressions (z<sup>(1)</sup><sub>v</sub> and z<sup>(2)</sup><sub>v</sub>) that combine the inputs. It seems obvious but it eludes me yet.

I am studying on my own (no background in CS or engineering). An explanation/ hint of how those sets were arrived at would help (I don't like glossing over things when I study). 
Thanks for your anticipated response.

(NOTE: mentioned text is available on archive.org : https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToTheTheoryOfFiniteStateMachines)

[Reference image (page 15 from mentioned text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y41Pt.png)

Comment: The copyright date on that book is 1962, you might be better off with a more recent book. Can in suggest "introduction to the theory of computation" as an alternative? Also, you might get a better response if you post this on one of the CS related networks.

Comment: thanks @Z4-tier I will look into the recommended alternative text.